# Changing fill/stroke of png on canvas created with 'Fancy Product Designer' plugin

Tags: jquery, canvas, fabricjs

http://www.carolineelisa.com/test/wordpress/product/heritage-rugby-shirt/

I would like to be able to edit the fill and/or stroke of elements on this canvas: http://www.carolineelisa.com/test/wordpress/product/heritage-rugby-shirt/

Using this code it seems I can target the png:

`var myProductDesigner = $('.fpd-container').fancyProductDesigner().data('fancy-product-designer');
var baseelement = myProductDesigner.getElementByTitle('Base colour');
alert(baseelement);`

Alerts:
`#<fabric.Image: { src: "http://www.carolineelisa.com/test/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/Shirt-Base4.png" }>`

Then I tried:
`baseelement.set({ strokeWidth: 2, stroke: 'rgba(100,200,200,0.5)' });`

That does nothing. But am I close? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Stroke' cannot be applied to a png.

In case it helps anyone, this got the 'fill' working:

```
var myProductDesigner = $('.fpd-container').fancyProductDesigner().data('fancy-product-designer');
var baseelement = myProductDesigner.getElementByTitle('Base colour');
var stage = myProductDesigner.getStage()
baseelement.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Tint({color: '#cccccc', opacity: 1}));
baseelement.applyFilters(stage.renderAll.bind(stage));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to create a stroke for my image as well. Is there any way to accomplish this? Which file do I edit/add this code? I'm not finding it in FPD.

Comment: I know you made this an answer because you don't have the reputation yet to leave a comment, but so you know for the future, since this doesn't provide an answer to the question it will be better put as a comment when you have the ability. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore, if you are having difficulty implementing the selected answer by accessing the baseElement, try using `getCustomElements()` to access user added elements.

```
var customElementTitle = myProductDesigner.getCustomElements()[0].element.title;
var baseElement = myProductDesigner.getElementByTitle(customElementTitle);
```